# Can I use the Calendar API with Expo?

Tags: calendar, expo

I did not find any documentation on using calendar Events from the device.. Anyone knows?

I googled but did not find any Information about it.

Answer (score 1):

Oh luckily i found there is a feature request list with this

https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/calendar-api

Edit ✨this feature is now in latest Version https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/calendar.html